# daily-canary Desktop install on Ubuntu Live Server

Tags: desktop-environments

A desktop installation for the Canary desktop seems to be supported in the cdimage daily-canary directory structure. Is there or will there be a installation package to install this desktop on a Ubuntu Live Server base? If it does currently exist, please reply with the installation instructions.

Comment: I'm very familiar with *canary* ISOs, as there have been many over the years (the most recent example I can think of is the `ubuntu-desktop-installer` before it became an official & released product used *canary* ISOs before 23.04, but that no longer applies. What do you mean by "*Canary Desktop*"?  There aren't any *canary* ISOs currently (at least [not for *mantic*](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/446/builds), and I'm unaware of any other current development product, though my concentration is largely Desktop systems, so aren't fully aware of all Core/Server products I suspect)

Comment: Are you instead asking about the `ubuntu-desktop-installer`, an actually released & named product (*it was called the canary installer less than a year ago, but was given a name being the primary desktop installer for Ubuntu 23.04 having ceased being a 'canary' product which it was for 22.10 or late 2022*)

Comment: A link to the exact "Canary desktop" image would be most clarifying.

Comment: When I see daily-canary directory and an installation ISO, that usually implies that the contents represents a customized installation of an environment. Many of these environments have the various supported desktops. I was assuming that canary was another desktop. I could not find any documentation for canary however there is an ISO maintained daily in the current Ubuntu directory structures.  Here is the URL https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-canary/current/mantic-desktop-canary-amd64.iso

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *kinetic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 13 October2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 October 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/kinetic-kudu-release-schedule/27263  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *kinetic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)